# Firebase.initializeApp name parameter is needed in mobile but not in web

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web

I have a Flutter app that works for Android, iOS and web. I use Firebase in main like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      // name: 'name',
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          // providers
        ],
        child: const MyApp(),
      ),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

When the parameter `name` is set, it runs in both Android and iOS, but in web it doesn't run. The window is created but stays white, and the console says:

> `[core/no-options] Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source..`

When I comment the same parameter, it runs in web, but I have the same problem in Android and iOS. It says:

> `flutter: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists`

How can I make it work for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the platform is `web` using `kIsWeb` and set `name` only if it's not `web`

```
if(kIsWeb){
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
 );
}else{
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'name',
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
}
```

Comment: It's there. I edited the question adding the whole code from main.

Comment: Try this, tell me if this works